# How to structure so that Ember uses fewer/no metamorph tags?

Tags: javascript

I'm using Ember.js/Handlebars to loop through a collection.
Have an issue with ember, wrapping it with script metamorphs and ember Div's in the produced output.

```
                <script type="text/x-handlebars">
                    {{#each App.PersonController}}
                      {{#view App.view contentBinding="this"}}
                         {{#with content}}
                         {{title}}
                        {{/with}}
                      {{/view}}
                    {{/each}}
                </script>
```

**Here is what it looks like:**

```
 <div id="ember304" class="ember-view">
 <script id="metamorph-0-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
 <script id="metamorph-2-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
 <div id="ember511" class="ember-view" aria-hidden="false"> 
    <script id="metamorph-23-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script> 
    <script id="metamorph-24-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
         Mr
    <script id="metamorph-24-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    <script id="metamorph-23-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script> 
</div>
</div>
```

How can I structure this, so that ember uses fewer no metamorph tags? so that my css doesn't break?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a collection view
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html

You can iterate through a list without using script tags.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you don't have this worked out yet...

What problems are you having exactly with your CSS?

A few general points on the things you mentioned:

Metamorph tags:

Ember needs to use the metamorph tags to support the bindings.  That said, it shouldn't affect  any CSS other than things like :first-child pseudo selectors.  They specifically settled on script tags as they had the lowest impact on layout.

Ember divs:

You can control the tag a view uses, as well as the CSS classes it uses, like so

```
window.AppView = Em.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    classNames: ['cssClass']
});
```

Hope this helps you, or someone else that stumbles on this question searching for something else (as I did).

Comment: Can we change the metamorph script tag from default Div to any other custom tag name?

Comment: You have to use a View, as shown above.  Then you can specify the tagName - the code above will render the view as a tablerow (<tr>)